# Why does R return an integer instead of a string

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an R function that will produce a string for later output. The data comes in a dataframe with one column and rownames.

```
fcc <- structure(list(temp = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("H", "M", "N", "S"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = "temp", row.names = 
  c(NA, 135L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

outStr <- "name"
for(i in 1:nrow(fcc)){
 if (fcc[i,] != "N"){
   outStr <- paste0(outStr," ", rownames(fcc)[i],"(",fcc[i,],")") 
 }
}
```

Instead of the characters "H","M", etc. that I expect R returns 1,2,etc.

When I type in fcc[i] at the command prompt I can see the character I need:

```
 > fcc[1,]
 Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

  temp
  1    N
```

I am pretty sure this is me misunderstanding factors, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your object isn't a "regular" data.frame. It's a `tbl_df` probably created from `dplyr`. Looks like this class has different subsetting rules. With normal data.frames, when you subset and only one column is returned, then the result is converted to a vector.

Look at the differences when you subset a `tbl_df` object and a standard `data.frame`

```
fcc2 <- as.data.frame(fcc)
str(fcc[1,])
# Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ temp: Factor w/ 4 levels "H","M","N","S": 3
str(fcc2[1,])
# Factor w/ 4 levels "H","M","N","S": 3
str(fcc2[1,, drop=F])
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ temp: Factor w/ 4 levels "H","M","N","S": 3
```

As discussed on the `?paste` help page, values are converted to characters via `as.character`. Which ultimately appears to attempt the conversion via `as.vector(, mode="character")` which is what is changing your value to character versions of the numeric index.

```
as.vector(fcc[1,1], "character")
# [1] "3"
as.vector(fcc2[1,1], "character")
# [1] "N"
```

Note also that your look really isn't necessary, you can index/subset/collapse all in vectorized operations.

```
paste(paste0(seq_along(fcc[[1]]), "(", fcc[[1]] , ")")[fcc[[1]]!="N"], collapse=" ")
```

Here we use `[[ ]]` to extract the factor vector from the `tbl_df` object so pasting works much better.